# Directory list recursive parent and child within

Tags: powershell

I would like to get a directory listing with `-recurse` but to show the sub directories right under the parent.

Here is what I tried:

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory -Depth 3 | Select-Object Fullname
```

The results show first top-level directories and only then level 2 and only then level 3

Example:

```
C:\Users\Moshe\onedrive\pictures\35mm_Film    (has no sub directories)
C:\Users\Moshe\onedrive\pictures\Camera imports
C:\Users\Moshe\onedrive\pictures\Camera Roll
```

and only then

```
C:\Users\Moshe\onedrive\pictures\Camera imports\Folder1
C:\Users\Moshe\onedrive\pictures\Camera imports\Folder2
C:\Users\Moshe\onedrive\pictures\Camera imports\Folder3
```

and then

```
C:\Users\Moshe\onedrive\pictures\Camera Roll\2014
C:\Users\Moshe\onedrive\pictures\Camera Roll\2016
```

I would like to get the list showing parent and right underneath its sub dir

For example:

```
C:\Users\Moshe\onedrive\pictures\35mm_Film    (has no sub directories)
C:\Users\Moshe\onedrive\pictures\Camera imports
C:\Users\Moshe\onedrive\pictures\Camera imports\Folder1
C:\Users\Moshe\onedrive\pictures\Camera imports\Folder2
C:\Users\Moshe\onedrive\pictures\Camera imports\Folder3
C:\Users\Moshe\onedrive\pictures\Camera Roll
C:\Users\Moshe\onedrive\pictures\Camera Roll\2014
C:\Users\Moshe\onedrive\pictures\Camera Roll\2016
```

it will also be nice to have the count of files for each directory but not crucial

For example:

```
C:\Users\Moshe\onedrive\pictures\35mm_Film 100
C:\Users\Moshe\onedrive\pictures\Camera imports 0 (no files in the parent)
C:\Users\Moshe\onedrive\pictures\Camera imports\Folder1  20
```

etc

Comment: You want something like this?  `dir -Recurse -Directory | group Parent | sort name | % {""; $_.Name + " (" + $($_.Group.Count) + ')'; $_.Group | sort Fullname | % FullName }`

Comment: The counts were for the number of the sub directories whining the parent. I was hoping to get the count of files within the sub directories. How can I change this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the directories in that order you can use [Sort-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object?view=powershell-7.2).

Example:

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory -recurse -Depth 3 | Select-Object Fullname | Sort-Object Fullname
```

This will give you the parent and their subfolders in order.

Comment: Simple and works. Thanks, I will try other suggestions to get the count.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this without the need of sorting afterwards the solution can be a bit cumbersome, you can either use a recursive [function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-7.2) / [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks?view=powershell-7.2) or as shown in this example, with a [`Stack<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.stack-1?view=net-6.0) and as optional you can use a [class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_classes):

```bash
class Tree {
    [int] $Depth
    [string] $Path
    [int] $FileCount
    hidden [IO.DirectoryInfo] $Instance

    Tree ([IO.DirectoryInfo] $Directory, [int] $Depth) {
        $this.Instance = $Directory
        $this.Path     = $Directory.FullName
        $this.Depth    = $Depth
        $this.CountFiles()
    }

    [IO.DirectoryInfo[]] EnumerateDirectories() {
        return $this.Instance.EnumerateDirectories()
    }

    [void] CountFiles() {
        $this.FileCount = $this.Instance.GetFiles().Count
    }
}


$stack = [Collections.Generic.Stack[Tree]]::new()
# define max Depth here
$maxDepth = 3
# initial path here
$path = 'C:\Users\Moshe\onedrive\pictures'
# define what you want to skip here
$attrToSkip = [IO.FileAttributes] 'Hidden'
$stack.Push([Tree]::new($path, 0))

while($stack.Count) {
    $folder = $stack.Pop()

    # this conditions stops the loop
    $reachedMaxDepth  = $folder.Depth -gt $maxDepth
    # this condition skips Hidden folders, remove it if you want to show all
    $isHiddenorSystem = $folder.Instance.Attributes -band $attrToSkip

    if($reachedMaxDepth -or $isHiddenorSystem) {
        continue
    }

    $folder

    foreach($i in $folder.EnumerateDirectories()) {
        $stack.Push([Tree]::new($i, $folder.Depth + 1))
    }
}
```

Comment: I never tried "programming" with powershell. I understand the solution but it is overkill.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I took the example from malexander and added some of the Daniel example and came up with this

`Get-ChildItem -Directory -recurse -Depth 3 | Select-Object Fullname | Sort-Object Fullname |  % {$_.FullName + " " + (Get-ChildItem $_.FullName| Measure-Object).Count}`

If understand correctly the Fullname is showing only once because it was piped to the % which shows both the name and the count.

Anyways, it gave me exactly what I needed.

Thanks to all

Comment: And just out put it to csv
```Get-ChildItem -Directory -recurse -Depth 3 | Select-Object Fullname | Sort-Object Fullname |  % {$_.FullName + " `t" + (Get-ChildItem $_.FullName| Measure-Object).Count} | Out-File "test.csv"```